# flatMap on a Tuple with spread operator not possible?

Tags: typescript

It seems I can't use `flatMap` on a Tuple with spread operator. Any reason why? Is there a work around for this?

```
type Groups = [
  { id: "start"; blocks: [{ type: "start" }] },
  ...{ id: string; blocks: { type: "a" | "b"; param?: string }[] }[]
];

const groups: Groups = [
  { id: "start", blocks: [{ type: "start" }] },
  { id: "yo", blocks: [{ type: "a" }] },
];


groups.flatMap(group => group.blocks)
                        //^ Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gM5QLxQNoCgpQDeUAlgCYBcUARKsAIZzDUDcUARgDYIDGA1qirZioSFVoMm1KAF8AurIA0+KADp1xclTpwSAOwDmbLrwFUR4COPrSAPjXasoYRvQC2Afm3Bdh2dgUZANw5FlxcHgQ9OigDRBRBWHi0TBwVTUoaOkZmRQ5ufkThKFErLMlmWUDlAgzxEARqPJNCoQsxGhsqpRCw8LjkNFVUThIeCAAKAEYASlUAM056YABZejAJgZRMAD5Y5NUWgRmgA)

Comment: You can pass a type parameter to `flatMap` or explicitly `map` and then `flat`: https://tsplay.dev/wXvjkm

Comment: Ok indeed, it can't infer the type correctly?

Comment: It's taking the first member of the union type, `{ type: "start" }` and using that as the expected return type. Since the rest of the elements in `Groups` have a different type, you get an error. Please use @pink to mention me in replies, or else I won't be notified.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @pink you can answer this 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like TS is using the first member of the union as the expected return type of the `flatMap` callback. You can help the compiler along by explicitly passing a type parameter with the type you want:

```
groups.flatMap<Groups[number]["blocks"]>((group) => group.blocks);
```

Or, you can explicitly `map` and then `flat`:

```
groups.map((group) => group.blocks).flat();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gM5QLxQNoCgoFQDeUAlgCYBcUARKsAIZzA0DcUARgDYIDGA1qmrYSoSNTqNmNKAF8AunIA0+QgDoNJCtXpxSAOwDm7bn0HVR4CBIYyAPrQ5soYJgwC2Afh3A9RudiKsoG48qy4uLwI+vRQhogoQrAJaJg4qgRaVLT0TCxKnDwCSSJQYtY5UixyQSqExGTZNCAINAWmxcKW4rS2Ncqh4bjxyGhqAGZcDMAAsgxgADzwo6jY+kjuHBBw8tg0HYI08gB8ABSnIygAlJjHcSlqB6hXQ5dj7vPnbzcYd2+PRUEVwmU2ApxeQA)